# Resolving goals containing existential quantifiers

Tags: lean

In the natural number game, the `use` keyword resolves goals which contain existential quantifiers by assigning a concrete value to the quantified variable. Using Lean by itself it looks like use isn't available; what do you do instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`existsi`](https://leanprover.github.io/reference/tactics.html#inductive-types), but in general the recommendation is to avoid using Lean by itself; mathlib should always be used as well. Set up your project [as documented here](https://github.com/leanprover-community/mathlib/blob/master/docs/install/project.md) then write `import tactic` at the top of your `.lean` file to get access to the `use` tactic.